# PostgreSQL: Outputting query of underlying function

Tags: postgresql

Someone once mentioned a way to make Postgres verbose, so that if you did `\dt` it would display all the underlying SQL.

I thought it was connected with `-a` or `-e` to echo the SQL, but I was wrong.  I seem to have forgotten that method and have tried to look it up without any luck:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

---

#### Edit:

I thought because this was database/sql related it was for stackoverflow, but this may need to be moved to [Super Users|Server Fault|Database Administrators] (?)

Comment: `psql -e -E [rest of options and arguments]` BTW: psql is *only a frontend*

Comment: @wildplasser put `-E` as the answer and I'll accept. I actually looked at that and said "nah, that can't be it" for some reason, but the description defines the vary nature of what I wanted. so... "doh!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

snipped from the output of `psql --help`:

```
  -e, --echo-queries       echo commands sent to server
  -E, --echo-hidden        display queries that internal commands generate
```

Answer (score 7):

To show the queries of internal commands,

**Method 1** : `psql -E` - including `-E` option while opening the console.

**Method 2** : `\set ECHO_HIDDEN noexec/on/off`, can be used while in session. `noexec` means it doesn't run the query, just prints it.